# Continue a function after an except

Tags: python

I have a function that just encrypts my files in a specific directories, and I'm using the `try` and `except` to avoid errors, and if there is a I just want my function to continue, and not exit the program.

My function is joing for a loop through my files, reading them and then encrypting the data and writing the cipher text to the file, but my problem is that if there is a error, for some reason (cant write a file, etc..) my program just stop.

How can I prevent my program from breaking my program and continue with the function if there is a error ?

**Encrypt function:**

You can see that I tried to take the length of the list from the `files` function, but it just continue the loop and not stop.

```
def encrypt(self):
        for i in range(0, len(files())):
            try:
                for file in files():
                    print(file)
                    with open(file, 'rb+') as f:
                        plain_text = f.read()
                        cipher_text = self.token.encrypt(plain_text)
                        f.seek(0); f.truncate()
                        f.write(cipher_text)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'{e}')
```

**Files function:**

This function is just taking my files and returns a list.

```
def files(pattern='*'):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in chain(os.walk(desktop_path), os.walk(downloads_path), os.walk(documents_path), os.walk(pictures_path)):
        for filename in filenames:
            full_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if filter([full_path], pattern):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches
```

Comment: Your code actually stops *looping* on an exception. Your `try..except` covers too much. (Add.: but why that double loop over the files?)

Comment: @usr2564301 This is what I said, that my code stops after an exception, do you have an idea to fix it ?

Comment: you used ```for i in range(0, len(files())):```  but no where in your code you used i

Comment: If you are not using an index in a for loop, it is customary to use underscore as a dummy variable, so use ```for _ in range(x):```

Comment: `except Exception` is considered bad practice.

Comment: @AMC So which exception should I use ? there is so many errors that can be happen there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `try ... except` statement is the first thing in the loop and so when that is executed, the loop ends. Try switching around the inner `for` and `try` like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(files())):
    for file in files():
        try:
            #code
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

שלום ובררוכים הבאים לסטאק אוורפלו!

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the file if an exception occurs.

```
for file in files():
    try:
        with open(file, 'rb+') as f:
            plain_text = f.read()
            cipher_text = self.token.encrypt(plain_text)
            f.seek(0); f.truncate()
            f.write(cipher_text)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'skipping file {file}. Reason: {e}')
```

Comment: Hey, In code I'm writing a lot of times to the same file.

Comment: I've cut the outer code and just pasted the relevant one, this does not mean you don't need the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You use `try` before you start looping the files. Which means it tries to loop your files once, then catches one exception, prints it, and then goes to the exception handler where it prints but at this point it is now outside your for loop

```py
try:
    for file in files():
        # your loop
except Exception as e:
    # Handles one exception, but never loops because the try contains the loop
```

You should put your `try` `Except` inside your for loop:

```py
for file in files():
    try:
        # your loop
    except Exception as e:
        # Handles one exception PRE FILE. After exception the loop continues.
```

This makes it so that it 'tries' each file in the loop once instead of 'trying' the whole loop once.